# How to only check intersection once using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, overlapping-features, duplication

If I've two polygons a and b. If a intersects b, then there is no need to check if b intersects a. How do I check this with the PyQGIS API to ensure I'm not getting duplicate features in my output vector layer? My code is below. I only want to add features to the new layer if they are not already in the new layer

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

feat = QgsFeature()
ok = features.nextFeature(feat)
all_features = [f for f in layer.getFeatures()]

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "HULL", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
f = QgsFeature()

while ok:
    polygon = feat.geometry()
    current_id = feat.id()
    rect = polygon.boundingBox()
    search_area = QgsRectangle(
        rect.xMinimum() - 1,
        rect.yMinimum() - 1,
        rect.xMaximum() + 1,
        rect.yMaximum() + 1)
    other_features = [x for x in all_features if current_id!=x.id() and x.geometry().intersects(search_area)] #If they dont have the same id, but intersect
    geoms = [polygon] + [x.geometry() for x in other_features]
    hull = QgsGeometry.unaryUnion(geoms).convexHull()
    f.setGeometry(hull)
    provider.addFeature(f)
    ok = features.nextFeature(feat)


QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: If I read your code correctly then you are not putting actual copied features from the original layer into the new layer but a union of various features. What exactly should be skipped then? Any feature in the main loop that was ever part of such union?

Comment: What is happening is it is creating two hull features for polygons that intersect as it's looping over each feature. I only want it to create one hull. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess what should be skipped is other_features if they already exist in the new layer